# How to return the remote array in array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There is the remote array that I have to fetch in React Native.
I can return "name" in the array but I can't return `url` in the array in an array.
This is my array.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Apple",
        "media": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 12,
              "attributes": {
                "url": "https://example.com/1.jpg"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Banana",
        "media": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 11,
              "attributes": {
                "url": "https://example.com/2.jpg"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

This is my React Native code.

```
<Text>{`${item.attributes.name}`}</Text>
<Image
  source={{ uri: item.attributes.media.??? }}
  style={styles.image}
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `item.attributes.media.data[0].attributes.url`, as long as data[] has an element at index 0.